# how to set height of widget dynamically in angularjs depending on the Content of the widget

Tags: angularjs, html

I need to set the  height of widget dynamically in angularjs depending on the Content of the widget .

```
s.seHeight = function (divName) {
    var divHeight;
    if (document.getElementById(divName) && document.getElementById(divName).clientHeight) {
        divHeight = document.getElementById(divName).clientHeight;
    }
    return (divHeight + 100);
}
```

Comment: Please add some codes. What have your tried right now? You may going to add a fiddle/plnkr example too.

Comment: I need to change the height of many div depends on the content of these div .

Comment: s.seHeight = function(divName) {
 
     
     var divHeight;
     if (document.getElementById(divName)
       && document.getElementById(divName).clientHeight) {
      divHeight = document.getElementById(divName).clientHeight;
     }
     return (divHeight + 100);
    
 }

Comment: this is my code source

Comment: Why not using CSS? Please create a fiddle or plnkr to make it repdroduceable. We need more information.